# android animate x and y position with ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, animation

i just search in google and at least mabye i found what i want i need to animate x and y position if View so i dont know if this code its what i need if what i need how can i get x and y in `onAnimationUpdate`

did this  `getAnimatedValue` will give me x Or Y ? did if i call it first time givme x and if i call it again its give me y i just beggener how can i get x and y inside function

```
onAnimationUpdate
```

this the code `valueX` the x value i want to animate to it `valuy` the y value that i want to animate view to it

```
 PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(chatHeadParent.SCALE_X, valueX);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(chatHeadParent.SCALE_Y, valuy);
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(chatHeadParent, pvhX, pvhY);
    animator.setDuration(50);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {


        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        //i need x and y position animate for use them 
          Log.d(" iiiiiiiiiii ",""+animation.getAnimatedValue()+"  "+animation.getAnimatedValue());
        }


    });

    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {


        }
    });

    animator.start();
```

Comment: use method getAnimatedValue(String propertyName)

Comment: @dtx12 did tis will give me the x value or y ?

Comment: @dtx12 please what the propertyName ?

Comment: use your chatHeadParent.SCALE_X and chatHeadParent.SCALE_Y as property names to get x and y

Comment: for example getAnimatedValue(chatHeadParent.SCALE_X) will return animated x for you